# Error in conforming with UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol while trying Custom Animations

Tags: swift, storyboard, xcode6, uiviewanimation, xcode6.3

I've been following a tutorial online about creating custom animations. So for making the custom animations, I created a class name Transition Manager of type NSObject. I'm facing two problems,

1) So when further defining the class as,

```
class TransitionManager: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, 
UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
{
    //Further Code
}
```

I get a compile time error,

```
Type 'TransitionManager' does not conform to protocol 
'UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning'
```

and

```
Protocol requires function 'transitionDuration' with type 
'(UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval'
```

Here is the 'transitionDuration' function:

```
// return how many seconds the transition animation will take
func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval
{
    return 0.5
}
```

2) Another compile time error pops up, at the following line:

```
  // get the duration of the animation

    let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)
```

Error:

```
  'TransitionManager' does not have a member named 'transitionDuration'
```

Here is the complete TransitionManager.swift: http://pastebin.com/LkLym5Ci

Comment: `transitionDuration` is outside the class calling it, that's why "  TransitionManager does not have a member named transitionDuration" happens. Put `transitionDuration` *inside* the `TransitionManager` class to fix this error.

Comment: Cool! I'm writing a proper answer so it could help other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `transitionDuration` method is currently *outside* the class, as shown in the PasteBin.

That's why you get an error message saying that `transitionDuration` is not a member of the class.

If you put the `transitionDuration` method *inside* the `TransitionManager` class the error will disappear.